# How to filter an s3 data event by object key suffix on AWS EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, triggers, aws-event-bridge

I've created a rule on AWS EventBridge that trigger a Sagemaker Pipeline execution. To do so, I have the following event pattern:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutObject", "CopyObject", "CompleteMultipartUpload"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["my-bucket-name"],
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "folder/inside/my/bucket/"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I have enabled CloudTrail to log my S3 Data Events and the rule are triggering my Sagemaker Pipeline execution correctly.

The problem here is:
A pipeline execution are being triggered for all put/copy of **any** object in my prefix. Then, I would like to trigger my pipeline execution only when a specific object is uploaded in the bucket, by I don't know its entire name.

For instance,  possible object name I will have is, where this date is builded dynamically:

```
my-bucket-name/folder/inside/my/bucket/2021-07-28/_SUCESS
```

I would like to write an event pattern with something like this:

```json
"prefix": "folder/inside/my/bucket/{current_date}/_SUCCESS"
```

or

```json
"key": [{
  "prefix": "folder/inside/my/bucket/"
}, {
  "suffix": "_SUCCESS"
}]
```

I think that Event Pattern on AWS do not support suffix filtering. In the documentation, isn't clear the behavior.
I have configured a S3 Event Notification using a suffix and sent the filtered notification to a SQS Queue, but now I don't know what to do with this queue in order to invoke my EventBridge rule to trigger a Sagemaker Pipeline execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at a similar functionality.

Unfortunately, [based on the docs from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html), it looks like it only supports the following patterns:

| **Comparison** | **Example** | **Rule syntax** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | UserID is null | "UserID": [ null ] |
| Empty | LastName is empty | "LastName": [""] |
| Equals | Name is "Alice" | "Name": [ "Alice" ] |
| And | Location is "New York" and Day is "Monday" | "Location": [ "New York" ], "Day": ["Monday"] |
| Or | PaymentType is "Credit" or "Debit" | "PaymentType": [ "Credit", "Debit"] |
| Not | Weather is anything but "Raining" | "Weather": [ { "anything-but": [ "Raining" ] } ] |
| Numeric (equals) | Price is 100 | "Price": [ { "numeric": [ "=", 100 ] } ] |
| Numeric (range) | Price is more than 10, and less than or equal to 20 | "Price": [ { "numeric": [ ">", 10, "<=", 20 ] } ] |
| Exists | ProductName exists | "ProductName": [ { "exists": true } ] |
| Does not exist | ProductName does not exist | "ProductName": [ { "exists": false } ] |
| Begins with | Region is in the US | "Region": [ {"prefix": "us-" } ] |

Comment: This is duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882690/aws-cloudformation-lambda-and-event-rule-lambda-not-getting-triggered-with-s3

Comment: Exactly. Until this moment, isn't possible to define a suffix for the key object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `EventBridge` has added this capability. [Suffix matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-suffix-matching) should do the trick..

```json
{
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["MY BUCKET"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "suffix": ".pdf"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide//ev-events.html) is the structure of events from `S3`.