# AWS Cloudformation Lambda and Event Rule - Lambda not getting triggered with s3 event with a suffix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have created a lambda and s3 event rule using cloudformation but lambda is not getting triggered as per configured rule.
As per event rule I want lambda to trigger whenever a file is created in a specific s3 bucket with a specific suffix.
Rule is given permission to invoke lambda. But when I upload a file (e.g. portfolio.testSuffix) lambda is not getting triggered.

```
  EventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: 'test s3 event'
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - 'aws.s3'
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - 's3.amazonaws.com'
          eventName:
            - 'CopyObject'
            - 'PutObject'
          requestParameters:
            bucketName:
              - 'test-bucket'
            key:
              - |
               {"suffix": ".testsuffix"}
      State: 'ENABLED'
      Targets:
        -
          Arn: !GetAtt TestLambda.Arn
          Id: 'TestLambdaTargetId'
  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt TestLambda.Arn
      Principal: 'events.amazonaws.com'
      SourceArn: !GetAtt EventRule.Arn
```

Can anyone help to identify what is wrong in this configuration and why lambda is not getting triggered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Eventbridge [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html#eb-create-pattern) the **suffix** pattern is not supported.

```
key:
 - |
  {"suffix": ".testsuffix"}
```

Here's a list of all the comparison operators available in EventBridge:

> Null, Empty, Equals, And, Or, Not, Numeric (equals), Numeric (range), Exists, Does not exist, Begins with

See [Content-based filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html) as well

Answer (score 3):

It seems that support for suffix was recently added, based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-suffix-matching).

| Comparison | Example | Rule syntax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ends with | FileName ends with a .png extension. | "FileName": [ { "suffix": ".png" } ] |

reference: [Content-based filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-suffix-matching)